# Can a Google Chrome tab id ever be zero?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Every tab in google chrome has an id that is unique for that browsing session, even across windows. The id is automatically assigned by chrome's internals when you call chrome.tabs.create(). Can this value ever be set to zero?

My reason for this question is that I would like to do a boolean test based on the id and I need a truthy value when there is an id.

Comment: no, but to put it simply, it makes sense in my case because I sort of use the tab id's as a foreign key for things where there can be no id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, tab IDs start at 1 and go up from there (they're stored as [SessionID](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/sessions/session_id.cc) instances). -1 may also be returned in [some cases](http://www.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/extensions/extension_tab_util.cc&l=42).